# Discord API only returns one member

Tags: api, discord

If I type `curl --header "Authorization: Bot TOKEN" "https://discord.com/api/guilds/GUILD/members` it only returns one member. The return:

```
[{"user": {"id": "213790766995210240", "username": "USERNAME", "avatar": "534d5eb58944314edcdf3e72dc57e564", "discriminator": "1385", "public_flags": 0}, "roles": ["722700978603687957", "722700978859540505", "727078437264556103", "753325209326584039", "753325723913289778"], "nick": "NICK", "premium_since": null, "joined_at": "2020-07-06T10:56:01.369000+00:00", "is_pending": false, "mute": false, "deaf": false}]
```

Do you know how to get all members?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downgrading discord.py by typing this into your terminal:

```
python3 -m pip install -U "discord.py>=1.4,<1.5"
```

Source: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Comment: I'm glad I could help!